# Dates Being sent to SQL in many different formats, how do i handle this?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date, formatting

I I'm busy with editing my stored procedures for Reports i created a while back.
I encountered a problem where the parameters being sent to the stored procedures comes in all kinds of funky formats from multiple computers.

Some of the formats i have encountered has been

'2017-01-31'

'2017-31-01'

'01-01-2017'

'31012017'

'20170131'

I desperately need a way to handle all these different formats.
the '31012017' gives me a input error so it doesnt even want to reach my Converter so i made the input parameter a VARCHAR(15) to take all kinds of inputs.

Comment: You need to fix the stored procedures to take proper data types -- a date in this case -- and then fix the calling code to pass that in.

Comment: with ambiguous formats and values ('01-01-2017'), you will always be just guessing

Comment: This definitely sounds like you need to have a conversation with the person/team who is providing the information.  Is it coming from a web form of some sort?  Can the application that processes the form be updated adjust for localization?  Depending on your use case, it might be better to fail when an incoming value is not parsable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best possible fix i found was the following(works for almost all formats)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLARE.png

This way it picks up which format whatever PC you are using is using and sends a standardized format to SQL

Answer (score 0):

You can make some educated guesses on the date format, there's however limit on how much you can guess.

Canonical dates ussually are ISO compatible so yyyy-mm-dd - I've never seen something like 2017-31-01.

The problem is when you get something like 11-11-2011 or - even worse - 10/11/12. There's no way to figure that out if you have no additional information.

Comment: Hey the comment below fixed the problem, it now accepts most of the formats....
i spent 2 days trying to get sql to accept all kinds of funky formats, when in the end all i had to do was change a property